# Update values within multidimensional array whilst building it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, order_no, reference, description, total_cost FROM bookorders
```

where the results within the while loop are building an array:

```
if (!array_key_exists($order_no, $orders)) {
    $orders[$order_no] = array(array(
        'reference' => $reference,
        'description' => $description, 
        'total_cost' => $total_cost,
        'discount' => 0,
        'total_cost_withdiscount' => $total_cost
    ));
} else {
    $orders[$order_no][] = array(
        'reference' => $reference,
        'description' => $description, 
        'total_cost' => $total_cost,
        'discount' => 0,
        'total_cost_withdiscount' => $total_cost
    );
}
```

and this is what it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [12345] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => abc
                    [description] => Book Product 1
                    [total_cost] => 8.99
                    [discount] => 0
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 8.99
                )   
        )  
    [67890] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => abc
                    [description] => Book Product 1
                    [total_cost] => 8.99
                    [discount] => 0
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 8.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => def
                    [description] => Book Product 2
                    [total_cost] => 24.99
                    [discount] => 0
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 24.99
                )
        )
)
```

In the same table there's also discount lines so for order **67890**, there was a discount of **8** for reference **def**.

Whilst running through the results from the query (which will bring out the discounts as a separate line), how can I find out if that reference already exists and update the 'discount' and 'total_cost_withdiscount' values?

So for the example above, I'd like to change this:

```
[67890] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => abc
                    [description] => Book Product 1
                    [total_cost] => 8.99
                    [discount] => 0
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 8.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => def
                    [description] => Book Product 2
                    [total_cost] => 24.99
                    [discount] => 0
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 24.99
                )
        )
```

To this:

```
[67890] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => abc
                    [description] => Book Product 1
                    [total_cost] => 8.99
                    [discount] => 0
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 8.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference] => def
                    [description] => Book Product 2
                    [total_cost] => 24.99
                    [discount] => 8.00
                    [total_cost_withdiscount] => 16.99
                )
        )
```

I need to update the values whilst I'm building the overall array within the while loop from the mysql query.  I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
if ($orders[$order_no]["reference"] == $reference)
```

### Edit

The discount is another line in the same table so the discount amount will come out as $total_cost.

So for above, it would be:

```
$id, $order_no, $reference, $description, $total_cost
1, 12345, abc, Book Product 1, 8.99
2, 67890, abc, Book Product 1, 8.99
3, 67890, def, Book Product 2, 24.99
4, 67890, def, discount, 8.00
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting the value for discount. If from another table then why not include this information within the original query.

Comment: i've edited the question above to explain how the discount lines come out of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reference_to_find = 'def';
$order_no_to_find = 12345;
foreach ($orders as $order_no => $infos)
{
    if ($order_no  == $order_no_to_find)
    {
        foreach ($infos as $index => $item)
        {
            if ($item['reference'] == $reference_to_find)
            {
                // change
                // $item['discount'] = ....

                // set
                $orders[$order_no][$index] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do this in my while loop while I'm building the array?

Comment: sure :). Try it, any problem, comment here.

Comment: it's finding the reference and updating the discounts with that result.  So, in my example above, if order_no 12345 had a discount on reference abc of £2, it would edit the discount and total_cost_withdiscount values fine but then would also update order_no 67890 with the same discount for the same reference...

Comment: this is what I've used (sorry for the formatting, can't make it look like the coding above!):
`foreach ($orders as $order_no => $infos) {

    foreach ($infos as $index => $item) {

        if ($item['reference'] == $reference && $item['order_no'] == $order_no) {

            $total_cost_withdiscount = $item['total_cost'] + $total_cost;

            $item['discount'] = $total_cost;

            $item['total_cost_withdiscount'] = $total_cost_withdiscount;

            $orders[$order_no][$index] = $item;

        }

        $total_cost_withdiscount = 0;

     }

}`

Comment: You need a order_no to make the info unique. Look at the updated answer.